# MongoDB Csharp: Dictionary of Lists "must implement IBsonArraySerializer and provide item serialization info"

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

This is simplified code of implementation.

**The Document**

```
public class Document
{
    public Dictionary<string,List<Information>> Data { get; set; }

    public class Information
    {
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**My Insert Action**

```
var doc = new Document
{
    Data = new Dictionary<string, List<Document.Information>>
    {
        { "Some Key", new List<Document.Information>
        {
            new Document.Information
            {
                Value = "Some Value",
            },
        }}
    }
};

myCollection.InsertOneAsync(doc);
```

**Now i want to query the data using**

```
var builder = MongoDB.Driver.Builders<Document>.Filter;
var filter = builder.ElemMatch(u => u.Data, w => w.Key.Equals("Some Key"));
var docs = myCollection.Find(filter).ToListAsync().Result;
```

**But iam getting the follwing exception**

> **System.AggregateException** The serializer for field 'Data' must implement IBsonArraySerializer and provide item serialization info.

### Question

#### How i can get serialization of Dictionaries of Lists to work?

## Update

This is how the data looks like in the database.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("560e44fffa67693da7db224f"),
    "Data" : {
        "Some Key" : [ 
            {
                "Value" : "Some Value"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide that data itself? How is it stored in MongoDB? ElemMatch only works on items stored as an array. Dictionaries, by default, are stored as an object, not an array.

Comment: The data is like i wrote in my answer. How can i change the default behavior for my needs ?

Comment: I perhaps wasn't clear. I meant how the data looks in MongoDB? Can you use the shell and provide the actual data itself?

Comment: @CraigWilson sorry for my late response. My question is updated and now contains the BSON data from the database.

Comment: Sorry for the questions. I started to answer you, but I don't know exactly what you are trying to do. What is your expected result here? Your dictionaries are serializing just fine. It's just the query we are having issues with and I'm not sure what your intended result is.

Comment: hello @dknaack, did you solve your issue? I am exactly in same situation